# Cannot retrieve value on rowdeleting in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I  have a problem for retrieving values for deleting records.
I'm using OnRowDeleting in a gridview with templatefields, and I can't retrive record selected value for deleting, this is my grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvw_Cli_Emp_EmpData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" Width="50%" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Font-Size="Small" OnRowDeleting="Borrando">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('Clientes_Empleados_Detalle.aspx?cliCod= <%#Eval("ClienteCodigo1").ToString() 
                        + "&EmpNom=" + Eval("Empleado1").ToString()
                        + "&EmpCod=" + Eval("IdCliEmp").ToString()
                        + "&idDepart=" + Eval("IdDepartamento").ToString()
                        + "&Depart=" + Eval("Departamento1").ToString()
                        + "&EmpNiv=" + Eval("NivelAcceso1").ToString()    
                        %> ','PrintMe','height=500px,width=800px,scrollbars=1');">Editar</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CLIENTE">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_CliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClienteCodigo1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CODIGO">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdCliEmp") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMPLEADO">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpNom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Empleado1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID DEP">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_DepId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdDepartamento") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DEPARTAMENTO">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpDep" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Departamento1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NIVEL">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpNiv" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NivelAcceso1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And for delete:

```
protected void Borrando(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string cell = gvw_Cli_Emp_EmpData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text; //this retuns me ""
    int EmpCliCod = Convert.ToInt32(cell);

    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, "Delete?", "Confirma", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        cliEmpBL.clientesEmpleados_SupEmpleado(EmpCliCod); //here execute deletion record from my datalayer 
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AlertScript", "alert('Deleted!');", true);
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    { }
}
```

So, as you can see returns me "".
I have tried resolve this, using:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.Label EmpId = e.Item.FindControl("lbl_CliEmp_CliCod") as System.Windows.Forms.Label;
    string val = EmpId.Text;
```

But same result, any idea?
please, I hope anyone can help me.

best regards

Comment: `MessageBox` is not an asp.net functionality. It's for winforms. Don't use `System.Windows.Form` in a web enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing below example, you will get id for selected row

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ClienteCodigo1")%>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>

protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
      int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      //now perform the delete operation using ID value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Patrik your solution helped me.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvw_CliEmp_EmpData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" Width="50%"  
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Font-Size="Small"
        OnRowCommand="gvw_CliEmp_EmpData_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gvw_CliEmp_EmpData_RowDeleting">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('Clientes_Empleados_Detalle.aspx?cliCod= <%#Eval("ClienteCodigo1").ToString() 
                        + "&EmpNom=" + Eval("Empleado1").ToString()
                        + "&EmpCod=" + Eval("IdCliEmp").ToString()
                        + "&idDepart=" + Eval("IdDepartamento").ToString()
                        + "&Depart=" + Eval("Departamento1").ToString()
                        + "&EmpNiv=" + Eval("NivelAcceso1").ToString()    
                        %> ','PrintMe','height=500px,width=800px,scrollbars=1');">Editar</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CLIENTE">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_CliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClienteCodigo1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CODIGO">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdCliEmp") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMPLEADO">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpNom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Empleado1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID DEP">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_DepId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdDepartamento") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DEPARTAMENTO">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpDep" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Departamento1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NIVEL">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpNiv" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NivelAcceso1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IdCliEmp")%>'>Eliminar
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and code behind:

```
#region ==== BORRAR REGISTROS DEL INGRESO ====

protected void gvw_CliEmp_EmpData_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int EmpCliCod = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, "Eliminar?", "Confirmar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            cliEmpBL.clientesEmpleados_SupEmpleado(EmpCliCod); //eliminar desde DL
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AlertScript", "alert('Eliminado!');", true);
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        { }

        gvw_CliEmp_EmpData.DataSource = null;
        gvw_CliEmp_EmpData.DataBind();
        gvw_CliEmp_EmpData.DataSource = cliEmpBL.clientes_Empleados_cons_EmpxCliente(lbl_CliEmp_CliCod.Text);
        gvw_CliEmp_EmpData.DataBind();
    }


}

protected void gvw_CliEmp_EmpData_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{//this is because grid fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled
}
#endregion
```